# How do I deploy WAPs of different brands in a secured fashion in a single campus?

Tags: cisco, wireless, hp

I have a requirement to deploy Cisco and HP WAPs in the same campus, in a secured manner. The Cisco has a WLC (Wireless LAN Controller), and an ISE, but HP has no WLC. In this scenario, how do I deploy both brands of WAPs in the campus, without compromising the Security. For more clarity, I have old HP WAPs and new Cisco WAPs, a Cisco WLC, and an ISE (yet to be deployed).

**Edit:**

We only have HP now. Cisco is yet to be supplied. Any plan which secures the wireless with the described infrastructure is welcome. First of all, I would like to know whether such a multi-branded WAP solution will work and how to secure it. I have old HP ProCurve 530, MSM-420 and MSM-422 in the campus, and now I am getting Cisco 2702-i, along with a WLC and ISE. How do I integrate the old HP WAPs and deploy the new infrastructure. We don't have RADIUS/LDAP/AD, so far.

Comment: can you add details about the SSIDs you are planning to deploy (same SSIDs on Cisco and HP ?) and the models of the devices (especially the HP)? Authentication settings (radius?) etc...

Comment: As @JFL says, we need a lot more information.  What are your security requirements?  How many HP APs?

Comment: We have only HP now. CISCO is yet to be supplied. Any plan which secures the wireless with the described infra is welcome. First of all, I would like to know whether such multi-branded WAP solution will work and how to secure it. I have old HP Procurve 530, MSM-420 and MSM-422 in the campus and now I am getting CISCO 2702-i along with WLC and ISE. How to integrate the old HP WAPS and deploy new infra. We don't have RADIUS / LDAP / AD so far.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend greatly on what "secured" is supposed to mean in this situation - RADIUS allowing you to use WPA2-enterprise is fairly decent, just slapping WPA2-personal on APs is generally kinda-low security, but may be adequate for some uses. Radius saves you from (and identifies) "password sharers."

My initial response was (and mostly remains) - Very tediously for the stuff without central control. Having moved from no central control to a system with central command/control (UniFi), the difference is night and day, even on a relatively small campus.

Multi-branded APs generally works fine so long as the SSIDs, security settings, and password or authentication method are **exactly the same** across any set that you want to work as a set, and you don't care about missing statistics, etc. from those that are not part of the centralized system.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and I got few inputs from you. I will go thru some more literature and come back to you once again. As suggested by you, I will try to install RADIUS for old HP WAPs. Thank you again.